# Does someone still have all the documentaton on Quickly?

Tags: python, quickly, gtk3

The project seams to be dead, but I am using it to create an app, but I need more documentation.

I cant run the quickly tutorial, maybe because I'm using elementary Freya, but I am missing a lot of thing because I need that documentation.

Does anyone know where to find this? Youtube videos and the wiki on ubuntu site are not enough, thanks in advance...

Also it s sad to see this project dead...